# Using time functions in Win32 application

Tags: winapi, visual-c++

I want to use time related method and function in Win32 VC++ application. VC++ provides CTime class. I want to know that using CTime class in non mfc project is safe. Is there any alternatives for CTime class for using in non mfc win32 application.

Thank you.

Comment: What do you actually want to do?

Comment: I want to get current system time, comparing two time, finding difference of two times and other mathematical operations on times, parsing time into string format etc.

Comment: If you aren't going to use mfc, what libraries are you going to use

Comment: I am not using any MFC libraries. My application is WIN32 non mfc application.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [GetSystemTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724390%28v=vs.85%29.aspx);

> Retrieves the current system date and time. The system time is
>   expressed in Coordinated Universal Time (UTC).
>
> To retrieve the current system date and time in local time, use the
>   GetLocalTime function.

A sample code piece.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>

void main(){

SYSTEMTIME st;
GetSystemTime(&st);

char currentTime[84] = "";

sprintf_s(currentTime,"%d/%d/%d  %d:%d:%d %d",
        st.wDay,st.wMonth,st.wYear, st.wHour,
        st.wMinute, st.wSecond , st.wMilliseconds);
std::cout<<"time: "<<currentTime;
getchar();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using MFC in a console (non GUI) application is safe.  Even the Project Wizard to generate a Win32 Console Application has a [checkbox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wydfdtb6.aspx) to specify whether to include the MFC libraries or not.